# Componer una suma con excel y visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

Sabrían de alguna función que busque los números que componen una suma y los muestre en una ventana emergente o en una celda específica, que tome esos valores de una tabla, de excel para buscar los valores.

Probé usando solver, pero me gustaria hacerlo con Visual Basic en excel

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Solver se puede usar desde VBA. En cualquier caso, tu pregunta es demasiado abierta. Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)